# How to return a list from a C++ mathlink function

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

If I wanted to return a list from a MathLink function, how could I do that?

```
:Begin:
:Function:  add
:Pattern:   add[x:{___Real}, y:{___Real}]
:Arguments: { x, y }
:ArgumentTypes: { Real64List, Real64List }
:ReturnType: Manual
:End:


/*What return type goes here?*/ add(double* x, int length, double* y, int length2)
{
    double* sum = new double[length];
    for(int i=0;i<length; ++i)
    {
        sum[i] = x[i] + y[i];
    }
    return /*What do I return? */;
}
```

Comment: You want to do this in *Mathematica*?

Comment: No. I'm linking C++ code into mathematica so that I can call it from mathematica. SAME, THO

Comment: See this page: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SettingUpExternalFunctionsToBeCalledFromTheWolframLanguage.html for details.

Comment: Go through this tutorial to familiarize yourself with MathLink: http://edenwaith.com/development/tutorials/mathlink/ML_Tut.pdf  Where is `sum` going to get freed?  You have a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so after mucking around in a lot of documentation I found out that the proper way to do this is to:

- Set the ReturnType to Manual
- Set the return type of the function to void
- Call "MLPutReal64List"

C++ code:

```c
#include "mathlink.h"

void add(double* x, int length, double* y, int length2)
{
    double* sum = new double[length];
    for(int i=0;i<length; ++i)
    {
         sum[i] = x[i] + y[i];
    }
    MLPutReal64List(stdlink, sum, length);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    return MLMain(argc, argv);
}
```

Template file:

```
:Begin:
:Function:  add
:Pattern:   add[x:{___Real}, y:{___Real}]
:Arguments: { x, y }
:ArgumentTypes: { Real64List, Real64List }
:ReturnType: Manual
:End:
```

Comment: You should `delete [] sum;` after `MLPutReal64List`.  C++ is not garbage collected.